# NVIDIA Screen Tearing problem

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, 14.04, screen, gpu

Recently I freshly installed Xubuntu 14.04 on my low-end computer.

Everything is working fine except that I'm experiencing screen tearing issues while I'm scrolling through a webpage. I thought I could live with it but after a while it starts to hurt my eyes.

I have installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers version 331.38. I'm using a dual monitor setup, both are the exact same models. GPU is the ASUS GT210 1GB.

Searched on the web a little bit and installed CompizConfig but I do not have the option to manual set the refresh rate of my monitors.

At this point I'm desperate and have no clue how to solve this issue, could anyone help out? Thank you very much.

Comment: Resolved this issue, will post the solution later.

Answer (score 3):

Managed to resolve my issue by using Compton. All credits go to the owner of this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144468

Follow the instructions there but make sure you disable the current composite manager first.

You can do this by:

- Click on the Xubuntu icon > Click on "All Settings" (bottom right corner)
- In the settings menu click on "Window Manager Tweaks"
- Click on the tab "Compositor"
- Disable "Display Compositing"

After disabling this, follow the instructions in the mentioned link. Hopefully this will help people in the future who experience the same issue.