# nvidia screen tearing in Xubuntu

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, screen, tearing

[nvidia-screen-tearing-problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458810/nvidia-screen-tearing-problem)

[How do I eliminate screen tearing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450593/how-do-i-eliminate-screen-tearing-on-14-04-and-xbmc-with-nvidia-331)

[Using Compton for tear-free compositing on XFCE or LXDE](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144468)

I have tried those solutions and i am still getting terrible image tearing on the screen while scrolling though a web page.
[image]

I have enabled `Sync to VBlack` and `Allow Flipping` in nvidia settings and added `compton -b` to start up.

[image]

output of `sudo lspci | grep NVIDIA`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT200 [GeForce GTX 260] (rev a1)
```

Driver in use.
[image]

xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "ViewSonic VA1926wSERIES"
    HorizSync       24.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 260"
    Option "Coolbits" "4"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Tearing will occur when using a web browser and using Ristretto image viewer all so tears as well. Video applications like game and flash videos are fine and have no tearing.

Image tearing will also happen in the file manager

Comment: Your screenshot and `xorg.conf` don't match... Screenshot says "version 340.93" but the configuration file says "version 331.20". Does that mean you have tried all earlier versions of nVidia drivers i.e. from 304.93, 304.128 etc.?

Comment: @clearkimura no i haven't tried other drivers.   I think that is the version of the nvidia-settings not the driver.

Comment: Don't use `compton` because it is not necessarily tear-free. Have you tried these two cases: 1. Xfwm compositor ON + nvidia driver, 2. Xfwm compositor OFF + nvidia driver? What were the results?

Comment: @clearkimura no change.

Comment: @clearkimura  There is no tearing on  video playback. yes the tearing will occur when using a web browser and using Ristretto image viewer all so tears as well. Video applications like game and flash videos are fine and have no tearing.

Comment: @clearkimura image tearing  will also happen in the file manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my problem by forcing a full composition pipeline

using this command to test it

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

and I made the changes permanent by adding this command to Session and Startup

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

[Solution was found in this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Avoid_tearing_with_GeForce_500.2F600.2F700.2F900_series_cards)

Worked Well for my GTX260 running Xubuntu 14.04 :D